# Replacing a deprecated create_function method

Tags: function, str-replace

I'm in the process of updating an abandoned plugin and I've come across this deprecated function that I'm strugling to find a suitable replacement for. The original function is this:

`$callback          = create_function( '', 'echo "' . str_replace( '"', '\"', $section['desc'] ) . '";' );`

What I came up with as a replacement is as follows:

`$callback          = function() { echo '"' . str_replace( '"', '\"', $section['desc'] ) . '";'; } ;`

However that fails due to the `$section['desc'] variable being defined outside of this function, so is giving an undefined variable error.

I've tried a number of different ways of passing the variable into the function, my latest effort fails with the output displaying (array) instead of the required description:

`$section_desc = $section['desc'];
                    $callback           = function( $section_desc ) { echo '"' . str_replace( '"', '\"', $section_desc ) . '";'; } ;`

Looking for suggestions as to the correct way to do this?

Comment: Does `$section['desc'];` contain an array normally? Did you try `print_r($section['desc']);` to check what is within the outputted array?

Comment: This is the gist of $section['desc']:

Comment: `$section['desc'] = __('The description.', 'plugin_textdomain' );

Comment: So it's a 2 item array then?

Comment: printr returns the description text as expected

Comment: Since the method for passing the variable into the function was yielding errors, I decided to try passing it as a global variable, and that worked! I'm not sure it's good practice using a global variable for that though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test because I'm on my phone, but I think this is right.

```
$section_desc = $section['desc'];
$callback = function($section_desc) {
  return str_replace('"', '\"', $section_desc);
}
```

Comment: That produces an invalid call back error, instead of passing a function that displays the text, it's passing the text.

Comment: That does not throw any errors, but also the text is not printed.

Comment: THis is a bit weird, I did a var_dump of $selection_desc outside the function and it returned the text string, however doing a var_dump of $selection_desc inside the function returns the whole selection array,, which is why it's throwing the array error when trying to echo the variable.

Comment: maybe try `$selection_desc['desc']` or `$selection_desc[0]` if its no longer found under `['desc']`

Comment: Instead of passing it within the function, I passed the variable as a global and that worked.